# Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am using React using with materialize. I have implemented a side-nav using materialize that appears when screen is smaller. When I click on the menu to display side-nav then click on one of the tabs my console show the error listed in the console and then my screen go to the clicked tab but it show a dimmed screen when the new page show. After clicking off screen is when the screen lights up again. I don't know how to fix this error I looked all over and cant find a solution. My site is hosted on Heroku so I can attach the link to the project. You can find the code to the project through the console. I would put the code up but its a project with a lot of files so I'll post the code to my Navbar component since it holds the side-nav code as well.

Link: https://reminder-me-website.herokuapp.com/

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import "../CSS/Navbar.css";
import bell from "../bell.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "firebase/app";
import { AuthContext } from "./Auth.js";
import M from 'materialize-css';

const Navbar = ({ tabs }) => {
  const { currUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const handleLogout = async (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerText === "Logout") {
      await auth().signOut();
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
     M.AutoInit()
    let input = document.getElementById("message");
    M.CharacterCounter.init(input);

  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nav-wrapper">
        <div className="brand-logo">
            <Link to="/About">
              Reminder Me 
            </Link>
          <img className="bell" src={bell} alt="bell" />
        </div>
        <a href="menu-selection" data-target="mobile-links" className="sidenav-trigger">
          <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          {tabs.map((e) =>
            currUser ? (
              <li key={e} onClick={handleLogout}>
                <Link
                  value={e}
                  className={e}
                  to={e === "Logout" ? "/Signup" : "/"}
                >
                  {e}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li key={e} className={e}>
                <Link
                  value={e}
                  className={e}
                  to={
                    e === "Login"
                      ? "/Login"
                      : e === "Sign Up"
                      ? "/Signup"
                      : "Login"
                  }
                >
                  {e}
                </Link>
              </li>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
          {tabs.map((e) =>
            currUser ? (
              <li key={e} onClick={handleLogout}>
                <Link
                  value={e}
                  className={e}
                  to={e === "Logout" ? "/Signup" : "/"}
                >
                  {e}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li key={e} className={e}>
                <Link
                  value={e}
                  className={e}
                  to={
                    e === "Login"
                      ? "/Login"
                      : e === "Sign Up"
                      ? "/Signup"
                      : "Login"
                  }
                >
                  {e}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a related [github issue](https://github.com/materializecss/materialize/issues/20) that can solve your issue.

The issue opener [doughballs](https://github.com/doughballs) proposed a solution:

> The fix, it seems, is to amend lines 132, 134 & 136 of sidenav.js. I
> honestly don't know what the broader implications of this are but the
> warnings disappear.
>
> Changed from:

`this.dragTarget.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleDragTargetDragBound); this._overlay.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleCloseDragBound); this.el.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleCloseDragBound);`

> to:

`this.dragTarget.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleDragTargetDragBound, { passive: true}); this._overlay.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleCloseDragBound, { passive: true}); this.el.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleCloseDragBound, { passive: true});`

Materialize contributor [DanielRuf](https://github.com/DanielRuf) commented:

> What's useful: you can append something like - closes #20 or - fixes
> #20 to a commit in a PR so GitHub links it to the relevant issue which is then automatically closed when the PR is merged, and there is some
> information like shown that it fixes / closes the mentioned issue.